# Do we want to change the link about MathJax help?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mathjax, hyperlinks

Stack Exchange sites with MathJax enabled have [a section in the editing help page on how to use LaTeX](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). This section contains a "MathJax help" link at the end.

By default, this "MathJax Help" link points to [this URL](https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/), but it turns out that the Community Team can change it to a different page, such as a post on our site's meta with a customized explanation of MathJax or, for instance, [Math Stack Exchange's comprehensive meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

We wanted to start a discussion in case folks feel strongly about changing the link. If you have an idea, please post it as an answer below, and if there's a consensus, we can let the Community Team know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one on the Math Stack Exchange site seems quite comprehensive. Also in its favour is that it has been there for quite a while so any flaws should have been spotted and corrected by now. I would not support writing a special one for this site as it would be a duplication of effort.

Comment: The "MathJax help" link on HSM.SE (and this Meta site) has been changed to point to [this Math Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), per your suggestion. Let us know if you encounter any problems!

Answer (score 5):

The "MathJax help" link on HSM.SE (and this Meta site) has been changed to point to [this Math Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), per the top answer to this discussion.

Let us know if you encounter any problems!

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't feel strongly about this link, and thing that the current URL it points to is just fine.